# Is iOS App Store Over-The-Air download limit based on 'Download Size' or 'Install Size'?

Tags: ios, download, app-store, app-store-connect, ota

I don't want to lose app installs on cellular due to the 100MB Over-The-Air download limit on App Store.

In this way, before I submit an app update to the App Store I always check the `App Store File Sizes` section of the current build in iTunes Connect to ensure the binary size will not exceed the OTA download limit.

Here's what iTunes Connect shows for my last app build, which is already published on the App Store:

[image: iTunes Connect]

and here's what the App Store shows on my iPhone 5S device:

[image: App Store]

Given this, I may assume the 'Size' field displayed on the App Store refers to the App 'Install Size'.

**Does Apple apply the OTA download limit based on the 'Install Size' (which is displayed to users on the App Store page as 'Size') or the 'Download Size' shown in the `App Store File Sizes` of iTunes Connect?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you hit the question mark next to "Download Size," you will see that it says "This is the compressed size of the app downloaded over the air."  This is the size used by Apple to determine if your app can be downloaded on a cellular connection.

The "Size" listed in the App Store can be different on different devices for a multitude of reasons: App Thinning, compression, etc.  As long as the compressed size of your app is under 100 MB (the size of the actual data downloaded), your users should be able to download it on a cellular connection.  But also note that if the user's device has enough disk space for the "Download Size," but not the "Install Size," they will not be able to install the application, as there will not be enough space on the device to unpack it.

Answer (score 1):

OTA is download size - the data the client needs to download in order to unpack and install the application.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has increased the cellular download limit from 100 MB to 150 MB, letting customers download more apps from the App Store over their cellular network.

[apple](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09192017b&1505856301)